# Existe alguma ferramenta que possibilite criar uma API utilizando como base meu banco de dados?

Tags: postgresql, api, rest

Tenho um banco de dados todo modelado e com uma massa de dados, agora preciso desenvolver uma aplicação que disponibilize através de uma REST API este banco de dados. Tenho duas frentes de desenvolvimento, a frontend e a backend. Existe alguma forma de disponibilizar este banco de dados como um REST API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solução para este problema é o [postgrest](https://github.com/begriffs/postgrest). Está ferramenta torna o banco de dados PostgreSQL uma REST API completa.

Utilizando esta ferramenta é possível que sua equipe frontend continue o trabalho de desenvolvimento conectando ao serviço REST e a equipe backend possa replicar a API utilizando a linguagem de programação backend do time.

Comment: Uma outra alternativa é usar [WCF Data Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/Cc668792(v=VS.110).aspx), neste caso você não estaria limitado a usar apenas o PostgreSQL, podendo migrar para outro Banco caso necessário.

Comment: Legal, não conhecia WCF Data Services. Obrigado pela dica!